# How do I keep my $_SESSION until I submit my form

Tags: php, session

Firstly thank you for reading this,
I have a form it has 3 pages with data needed to be store from page 1 and page 2 and finally on page 3, then it gets sent to the database.

I use this on page 2 to store info from page 1
(assuming on page 1 of my form has session_start();)

```
$_SESSION['firstName']= $_POST['firstName'];
$_SESSION['telephone']= $_POST['telephone']; 
$_SESSION['surname']= $_POST['surname'];
$_SESSION['mobile']= $_POST['mobile'];
```

Then page 3 gets information from page 2 using this to keep the info.

```
 $_SESSION['address1']= $_POST['address1']; 
 $_SESSION['address2']= $_POST['address2'];
 $_SESSION['address3']= $_POST['address3'];
 $_SESSION['email']= $_POST['email'];
 $_SESSION['customerType']= $_POST['customerType'];
```

It works to a point if I echo $_SESSION['email'] on page 3 it shows up BUT IF I echo any $_SESSION from page 2 on my final page it doesn't show up anything.

I've spent ages looking at storing sessions, but I can't seem to work it out.

**To summerise:-**

- PAGE 1 Starts the session (session_start()) and user enters their Name, Number Surname and Mobile.
- PAGE 2 Stores the information inputted by the user on Page 1 and users enter their address, email and select membership type.
- PAGE 3 Stores the    information inputted by the user on Page 2 and user selects payment method(no payment is taken as I just want to know how a member would like to pay ,so cheque or paypal)
- PAGE 3 also has one piece of info which isn't stored as the page
  Submits all the information to the database.

Problem on PAGE 3 no data from PAGE 1 is displayed if I try to ECHO any info from PAGE 1 I get  this error :- **Notice: Undefined index:**

Thank you once again for reading this, and sorry as I am new so this is prbablya stupid question to many of you, but I want to learn and this site is great.

Sorry forgot the add this, I have a main page called Default.php which includes this code:-

```
 if ($_REQUEST['p']) { include('includes/'.$_REQUEST['p'].'.php');
```

all my pages then are called from this page which is in the following format

```
  default.php?p=addmember
  default.php?p=addmember-page2
  default.php?p=addmember-page3
```

**default.php has the session_start(); so every page has this called**

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you want to submit three thing in one page, one after the other, by storing sessions ? is that it?

Comment: Yes I have 3 pages all which have information a user enters, and then they all have to be submitted on page 3 after the user enters the final piece of information on page 3.

Comment: Gimme 2 minutes, I'll make something up.

Comment: Oh my goodness really? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yea, I am going to need some more minutes and I will only create a script in which you can post all in one page, one by one using sessions

Comment: Thank you so much, I have spent the last 8 hours trying to work this out. You really don't realise how much I appreciate this.

Comment: @I am not sure, if it is working 100%, but I'll fix it tomorrow, when I am not sleepy, till then, you can get the idea behind it, or If I have completely, missed it, you can tag me anytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
#session_destroy();
function form($type)
{
    return "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\" >
            <input type=\"text\" name=\"next\" />
            <input type=\"submit\" name=\"$type\" />
            </form> ";
}

function module()
{
    echo form('one');
    if (isset($_POST['one'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['next']) && !empty($_POST['next'])) {
            $_SESSION['title'] = $_POST['next'];
        } else {
            echo "post is empty";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please fill the field";
    }
}

function module2()
{
    echo form('two');
    if (isset($_POST['two'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['next']) && !empty($_POST['next'])) {
            $_SESSION['content'] = $_POST['next'];
        } else {
            echo "post is empty";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please fill the field";
    }
}

function module3()
{
    echo form('three');
    if (isset($_POST['three'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['next']) && !empty($_POST['next'])) {
            $_SESSION['category'] = $_POST['next'];
        } else {
            echo "post is empty";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please fill the field";
    }
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['title'])) {
    echo module();
} else if (isset($_SESSION['title']) && !isset($_SESSION['content'])) {
    echo module2();
} else if (isset($_SESSION['content']) && !isset($_SESSION['category'])) {
    echo module3();
}

// you can delete, below this line. 
echo "<div style=\"width:1000px; align:left; border:1px dashed #darkblue; color: darkblue; font-size:14px;  \" />";
function SessionChecker($type)
{
    if (isset($_SESSION[$type]) && !empty($_SESSION[$type])) {
        echo "Session $type is set as <b>" . $_SESSION[$type] . "</b><br/>";
    } else {
        echo "Session '$type' is not set <br/>";
    }
}

echo SessionChecker('title');
echo SessionChecker('content');
echo SessionChecker('category');
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialise the session using `session_start()` in each page.

Comment: Yes, `session_start()` is used both to start a new, or resume an already started session. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: If I use session_start I get the following **Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()**

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `session_start()` called on every page?

`session_start()` creates a session or resumes the current one and you would therefore need to call this at the top of every page, not just your initial page.

Comment: Okay sorry I'll add this also to the main question. I use one page called default.php and then I use this **if ($_REQUEST['p']) { include('includes/'.$_REQUEST['p'].'.php');** so i use **default.php?p=customer**add and it runs off of default then for every page. Default.php has the session_start();